# Call a function according to the elements of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am a beginner in JavaScript and jQuery, and I would like to have an idea to how to proceed with this part of a code,

I have a function with a callback, for example:

```
myFunc(elem, callback) {
    $(elem).fadeIn(function(){ callback(); });
}
```

and I want to run this function for elements that are in an array:

```
elems = ['#elem1', '#elem2_3', '#elem4_5', '#elem3', '#elem_five'];
```

but, I want to execute this function for each element of the array, one by one through the callback.
eg. once #elem1 has fadein, it must fadein second element ..etc

now I proceed like this:

I have tried to do a for loop, but they are executed in the same time.

```
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
    myFunc(elem[i], function(){
        if (elem[i+1]) {
            myFunc(elem[i+1]);
        }
    });
}
```

So how would you proceed?

Comment: You want every element fedeIn one after one right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this, A recursive solution for your problem,

```
function myFunc(elems, cnt)
{
   if(cnt > (elems.length - 1)) { return; }
   $(elems[cnt]).fadeIn("slow", function(){  myFunc(elems , ++cnt); });
}

myFunc(['#elem1', '#elem2_3', '#elem4_5', '#elem3', '#elem_five'], 0);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yoja1suh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 var elems = ['#elem1', '#elem2_3', '#elem4_5', '#elem3', '#elem_five'];
    var len = elems.length;

    function myFunc(index) {
        $(elems[index]).fadeIn(function () {
            if (len > ++index) myFunc(index);
            return;
        });
    }
    myFunc(0);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sqL17sj1/2/)

Comment: Question asker is speaking about array of element ids. Would this code work if all the elements not being siblings to each other?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy That is why i gave sample html

Comment: I think you are not getting my point.. Have you read this part from the question? **and i want to run this function for elements that are in an array:**

Comment: Yeah.. Great solution, but anyway polluting the global scope making me uncomfortable.. Three variables seems being populated in the global scope..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy In your code The elems.length - 1 , every time it  will call length function in loop

Comment: Superb point.. but I won't fix it. Because it seems like removing the entire leg for a small injury in it. The argument is growing like an unproductive one. Let's stick with our own points. No offence. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy your calling length function unwanted in each time , that is i suggested use **var len = elems.length;**  , If You use global variable that wont kill the application , what is global scope it will use some other places , avoiding repeated calling

Comment: Dai.. Poda.. :) chandru va koopidava..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy He is absent today , but i have socket problem , it wont refresh it self

Answer (score 0):

Update on link:
http://jsfiddle.net/kuw6tt92/1/

```
function fadeIn(selectors) {
    var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call($(selectors));
    function fade() {
        jQuery(elements.shift()).fadeIn("slow", fade);
    }
    fade();
}
fadeIn("div");
```

Comment: what is the purpose of pushing the elements into an array before doing the fading?

Comment: Because jquery is working with array like objects. but your right it could be an array, simply writen